# Can SELECT and WHERE LINQ clause be combined?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is what I have done to `Select` users into my model and then remove all the `null` records:

```
        model.Users = users
            .Select(u =>
        {
            var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName);
            return membershipUser != null
                ? new UserBriefModel
                {
                    Username = u.UserName,
                    Fullname = u.FullName,
                    Email = membershipUser.Email,
                    Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
                }
                : null;
        })
            .Where(u => u != null)
            .ToList();
```

Wondering if there is a way to combine the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clause.

I tried:

```
        model.Users = users
            .Select(u =>
            {
                var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName);
                if (membershipUser != null)
                    return new UserBriefModel
                    {
                        Username = u.UserName,
                        Fullname = u.FullName,
                        Email = membershipUser.Email,
                        Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
                    };
            })
            .ToList();
```

But the intellisense suggest a syntax error. Which forces me to add a `return null` statement:

```
        model.Users = users
            .Select(u =>
            {
                var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName);
                if (membershipUser != null)
                    return new UserBriefModel
                    {
                        Username = u.UserName,
                        Fullname = u.FullName,
                        Email = membershipUser.Email,
                        Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
                    };
                return null;
            })
            .ToList();
```

So what is the correct way to write this `SELECT` statement so only valid records are selected into my model?

Comment: What's the build error you're getting? Also I'd suggest doing your null check before you try to use the entity otherwise you'll get null refs inside your linq which is a pain to diagnose

Comment: Why? What is the problem with separating the where from the select?

Comment: Just want to know if it is possible to combine the two. It feels a bit ugly to first populate the model with some useless records and then filter them out. Wouldn't it be better to discard `null`s in the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: In the second code example you lambda is incorrect - What does it return when memebership is null? Lambda, anonymous methods are the same methods - they should be correct methods to be used.

Comment: Sometimes a foreach statement is cleaner than LINQ.  I think this might be one of those cases.

Comment: @Blaise: What user store are you using? Are the users stored in the DB?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conceptually you actually have three operations here:

1. project the user name to a membership user
2. filter out null membership users
3. project the membership users to a model

*That* is how your query should be looking.  Your very first query has already tried to combine steps 1 and 3 together, but you're struggling because step two really *should* be in the middle of the two, and the hoops that you need to jump through to get around that aren't pretty.

The query actually becomes simpler and readable (and becomes idiomatic LINQ code) when you represent all three operations individually.

```
model.Users = users
    .Select(user => new
    {
        user,
        membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(user.UserName)
    })
    .Where(pair => pair.membershipUser != null)
    .Select(pair => new UserBriefModel
    {
        Username = pair.user.UserName,
        Fullname = pair.user.FullName,
        Email = pair.membershipUser.Email,
        Roles = pair.user.UserName.GetRoles()
    })
    .ToList();
```

This is a query that can also be written more effectively in query syntax:

```
model.Users = from user in users
                let membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(user.UserName)
                where membershipUser != null
                select new UserBriefModel
                {
                    Username = user.UserName,
                    Fullname = user.FullName,
                    Email = membershipUser.Email,
                    Roles = user.UserName.GetRoles()
                };
```

As for the literal question of whether or not you can combine the projecting an filtering into a single LINQ operation, it is certainly possible.  It would be an inappropriate solution to the problem, but the use of `SelectMany` can allow you to filter and project at the same time.  This can be done by projecting the item to either a one item sequence containing the value that you want to project it to or an empty sequence based on the predicate.

```
model.Users = users
    .SelectMany(u =>
    {
        var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName);
        return membershipUser != null
            ? new[]{ new UserBriefModel
            {
                Username = u.UserName,
                Fullname = u.FullName,
                Email = membershipUser.Email,
                Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
            }}
            : Enumerable.Empty<UserBriefModel>();
    }).ToList();
```

Of course, every time you use this code, a kitten is killed.  Don't kill kittens; use the earlier query instead.

Comment: How come I got -2, and guy that copied my post got +3.

Comment: @LIUFA Well, I didn't even see your post until you mentioned it, and didn't vote on it, so I can only guess, but a few things stand out.  First off, you had a pretty noticeably different answer when you first posted, and edited it later. I'm not sure when the votes came in, but they may have been based on your first revision. Next, and more importantly, your answer doesn't *explain* anything. Just posting some code without explaining what you've changed, and why you changed it, radically affects the value of the post.  Finally, the code in my answer *isn't* the same as yours, although similar.

Comment: I just spent like 20 minutes figuring out how to do it with only ``SelectMany`` to correct my answer and you still beat me...Damn you Servy

Comment: @KyleGobel Now you can [try Eric's challenge](http://ericlippert.com/2013/03/25/monads-part-ten/) and implement (an inefficient) `Join` in terms of `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, `Select` will map everything 1-1 as far as I know...if you're trying to filter you will need a `Where`.

edit edit:
I **<s>no longer</s>** believe `SelectMany` can do it (As Servy has shown).

Comment: Fairly certain, then, that you believe wrong. `SelectMany` allows you to flatten lists of lists typically, and results in more elements, not less. It is a select, but in no way a filter.

Comment: @Blaise Can't say anything about `SelectMany` but I'm pretty certain the first part of the answer is correct. I don't think you'll be able to squeeze them into 1 method unfortunately.

Comment: @TzahMama: `SelectMany` is an incredibly useful method which allows you to turn a tree structure into a list to operate on: You could do something like `users.SelectMany(user => user.UserName.GetRoles())` and the result would be a list of all roles any user has, likely with duplicates. It's valuable, just not relevant here.

Comment: My bad, I was more or less under the impression that ``SelectMany`` could do just about anything with a little magic and trickery

Comment: @KyleGobel: But now as a result, you'll be able to use it correctly! This answer has resulted in a net gain of knowledge.

Comment: @KyleGobel It is actually *possible* to use `SelectMany`, and you can actually implement almost all LINQ operations (although they'd be horribly inefficient in terms of `SelectMany`.  But while it would be *possible*, it's not the correct tool for the job, and so it really *shouldn't* be used here.

Comment: @Servy thanks.  I knew it would def be the wrong the tool for the job, but the question was can select and where be joined in one clause, I said SelectMany could probably do the job (although I wasn't sure), I was in not trying to imply you should do that...I certainty wouldn't.

Comment: @KyleGobel The answer, as it stands, is simply wrong, in stating that it's not possible.  It is.  The answer as it was before, stating that it's possible, but not stating how, isn't particularly helpful, because knowing that it's possible without knowing how doesn't help the OP solve his problem.  Of course, the whole thing is made all the more inappropriate given that it shouldn't be done, even though it's possible.

Comment: If you feel that your answer is no longer applicable, you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any Linq method which will allow you to arbitrary add or to not add the value into the resulting IEnumerable.

To do it the lambda(selector, predicate, filter...) should be able to control this addition. And only predicates(Where) are able to do it. In your case you  will have to execute predicate(Where) and Select. There is no combinational method which will do both for you at the same time, except one non-direct method described in the end of the answer.

```
model.Users = users
   .Where(u => Membership.GetUser(u.UserName) != null)
   .Select(u =>
    {
       return new UserBriefModel
         {
             Username = u.UserName,
             Fullname = u.FullName,
             Email = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName).Email,
             Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
          };
    })
    .ToList();
```

We either get two Membership.GetUser(u.UserName) with such prefiltering or we will end with your original postfiltering.

That's just shifting the complexity. And it is difficult to say where the performance will be better.
It depends on whether the `Membership.GetUser` is fast and there are a lot of non-membership users - for my example. Or if `Membership.GetUser` is resource-consuming and there are few non-membership users your example with postfilter is better.

As any performance based decision it should be thoroughly considered and checked. In most cases the difference is minimal.

As it was already shown in the another post and pointed by Mr. 'Servy' it is possible to do so using one call of `SelectMany` SelectMany selecting either empty IEnumerable or 1-element array. But I still consider the first statement to be technically correct, because SelectMany returns collection of elements (it does not exactly add or doesn't add single element directly):

```
 model.Users = users
       .SelectMany(u =>
       {
           var membership = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName);

           if (membership == null)
               return Enumerable.Empty<UserBriefModel>();

           return new UserBriefModel[]
           {
               new UserBriefModel()
               {
                   Username = u.UserName,
                   Fullname = u.FullName,
                   Email = membership.Email,
                   Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
               }
           };
       })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(u.UserName); if (membershipUser != null) ... is turned into .Where(u => Membership.GetUser(u.UserName) != null). I don't see any error. Sorry I am mistaken

Comment: A bit of duplication, but I don't think much can be done there. I still like the looks of it better than OP's.

Comment: Yes, LINQ looks better without conditional statements. But that's not the point.

Comment: The point is whether or not select and where can be combined, which is addressed here. This answer is a correct answer.

Comment: @Magus But the two *can* be combined.  The answer is incorrect to state that they cannot be.  Now, they *shouldn't* be combined.  It would be very poor practice to do so, but it is absolutely possible.

Comment: The question is whether there is a way to achieve the result with one IEnumerable LINQ method or do you have to use both the Select and the Where to get correct results.

Comment: @Servy: You could indeed define your own that does both, and that would indeed be both possible and bad, but it is still true that out of the box, there is no method that does so.

Comment: @Magus & Eugene I'm aware of that, and I'm asserting that you *can* project and filter with a single LINQ method, without writing your own LINQ-esque method.  You shouldn't, but you absolutely *can*.  That method is `SelectMany`.

Comment: @Servy: That's right up there with stating 'well technically you *can* call private methods using reflection` - Indeed true if you're feeling particularly pedantic, but also a clear misuse of a tool. You *can* do just about anything with anything. But to say 'well technically you can misuse this thing here so there is a way' does not provide benefit. You're simply stroking your own ego.

Comment: @Magus You were the one that went out of your way to say that the post technically answered the literal question that was asked correctly, and that that is what is important here.  Now if you want to say that that aspect of the answer is irrelivant, and that what really matters is the solution to the actual problem, rather than the question, than that's fine.  I have no problems with that.  But if you want to assert that it's not *possible* to perform a projection and filter in a single LINQ query then that statement is incorrect.  The first half of this answer is wrong.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is possible to do so with monstrous code using SelectMany selecting either empty IEnumerable or 1-element array such a method looks awful. I will edit my question.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Since the first two paragraphs of your answer are incorrect, and it is possible, you should probably remove them or re-write them, because it *is* possible.  If you want to edit it to simply say that there is no idiomatic way of doing that, then that would be fine to, but as it stands, it is not correct.

Comment: @Servy: As you say, that there is no idiomatic way is the correct answer. The fact that you felt so compelled to prove me wrong, just to agree that it'd be wrong anyway is slightly troubling, but I suppose more knowledge isn't bad for anyone.

Comment: I think we should not begin any discussions on political and religious topics in programming and formal proofs. They usually does not end well. There is always another point of view. That's all.

Comment: Your statement that `SelectMany` doesn't accomplish the stated goals is not correct.  Used in that manor it will function identically to a `Select` and `Where` call.  All three operators are simply yielding results to a new sequence based on the parameters given.  Neither is actually mutating an existing collection in some way.  On a [conceptual level they really are the same](http://ericlippert.com/2013/03/25/monads-part-ten/).  The implementation is a bit more inefficient, and it harms readability, but at a true conceptual level, it's not doing something entirely different.

Comment: @Servy: I agree that your post is correct and more comprehensive. And I have upvoted it long ago even before the SelectMany.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single method to accomplish this:

```
private IEnumerable<UserBriefModel> SelectUserBriefModels(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(user.UserName);
        if (membershipUser != null)
        {
            yield return new UserBriefModel
            {
                Username = user.UserName,
                Fullname = user.FullName,
                Email = membershipUser.Email,
                Roles = user.UserName.GetRoles()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
model.Users = SelectUserBriefModels(users);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
model.Users = users
    .Where(u => u.Membership != null)
    .Select(u => new UserBriefModel
            {
                Username = u.UserName,
                Fullname = u.FullName,
                Email = u.Membership.Email,
                Roles = u.UserName.GetRoles()
            })
    .ToList();
```

First filter, then select. For this solution you need to have a navigation property so you can do `u.Membership.Email` instead of the `membershipUser.Email`.

My users look something like:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    // other properties

    public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }
}
```

where `Membership` is the entity representing the membership table and is mapped via:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
   .HasRequired<UserProfile>(m => m.User)
   .WithOptional(u => u.Membership);
```

Then you can select everything with **one query**. Some other solutions here also work fine, but every call to `Membership.GetUser(u.UserName)` results in one additional DB call.

Comment: Your code selects something entirely different. Where is the call to `Membership.GetUser`?

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen is right. I am checking `Membership.GetUser(u.UserName)`.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen: Now I changed it - this way it is/was working in my code.

Comment: @chrfin This is not OP's problem

Comment: @TzahMama: It is a working solution to the OP's problem (select a `UserBriefModel` for every user which has a membership account) with the added benefit of much less DB queries - I use that in my app that way...

Comment: More down-votes? Please tell me whats wrong with my solution, so I can improve.

Comment: @chrfin OP _has_ a working solution. He asked if there is a way to use only 1 linq method instead of `Where` & `Select`. Writing it in a different way is just not what he asked for

Comment: @TzahMama: At the end he asks `So what is the correct way to write this SELECT statement so only valid records are selected into my model?` and for this I think my solution is an (alternative way but still) answer. Or is it not allowed anymore to suggest alternative (and maybe better) ways to the base problem of the OP?